# How to correctly leave your company

Tags: job-change

I am in a small development company. I am fine and I like the people there, but I have just been offered a job and it is really interesting. So I have decided to accept it. I was not looking for it, but it just happened to come by, a friend of mine told me about it and I applied just to see how it was.

Now, right now we are in a very high workload moment. And honestly I was starting to burnout since my project's client is being unrespectful sometimes with us the developers. 2 months ago this would have been easier but now I know it will be a pain for some people that I leave. I don't need to go right now, I can stay for 2/3 weeks. (In fact, my boss can require by law that I stay and I have no problem). But somehow I still feel bad. Maybe it is because is the first time I have to go through that.

How should I proceed? I am thinking in helping looking for a replacement during these last days too. Do you think is there any reason for someone to get mad at me?

Comment: For what it's worth, I've never even heard of someone outside of management getting upset with someone for leaving their job outside of some highly specific and unusual circumstances. "It's harder to get the work done with fewer people" is just a fact of life. And while it's reasonable to be disappointed a good employee is leaving only a bad manager would get angry at you.

Comment: What jurisdiction?  The legal obligations vary hugely (and in most cases will include "check your contract"), but the culture varies as well.

Answer (score 19):

1. You resign giving whatever notice is required by your contract/law or whatever is customary for your job.
2. You professionally work your notice period, doing whatever you are directed by your manager to do.

That's it. It's your employer's job to ensure they have enough staff, not your's - and always remember that if they decide to let you go, they won't give you a day's notice more than they are legally required to.

Comment: I am inclined in thinking this way since this is business, and at the end of the day, if you do what you are required, you are doing everything ok. I don't have any problem in giving a little extra since they have been nice with me. Do not get me wrong, I don't have any reason to think they will get mad, but I have never left a company before like this.

Comment: You should be aware that when you give notice, you *may* be placed onto garden leave or your contract may be immediately terminated (depending on the laws in your area) - so be prepared for that.

Comment: I would add one thing : Even if your manager doesn't ask you to, make whatever you can to smooth the transition for the next person : document your work, leave notes.

Answer (score 6):

My recommendations:

1. Let your manager know, officially using the procedures in use at your company, that you are leaving.  Suggest a last date in accordance with laws, contracts, or customs but be open to their requests, within reason, for a longer or shorter transition period.
2. Be professional at all times and that includes doing what your management asks you to do during the transition period.
3. Go quietly.  No need for an email blast either thanking everyone or complaining about anything and everything.  If there are some co-workers who you have developed good relationships with, you should say goodbye to them personally and privately.

Comment: This is more or less what I was thinking. I obviously intend on doing what I should during the notice period. I am working at the office so typically when someone leaves just stops the room for a moment, gives thanks to everyone for the good environment (which is true) and then when the time comes to leave it just leaves and maybe it brings some chocolates or whatever if they are keen to (I am from Spain and this is not the norm but not so unusual, I've seen it happen before)

Comment: This is the answer I like the best so far without offering a competing one. The other answers are a cold rendition of "cut, print, that's a wrap". I like that your answer keeps to professionalism and still makes reference to the idea that there are people involved. While there is not a legal requirement to do more, OP should always obey their own ethical requirements to assist and just be a good person to the people around them. Be professional, follow your values, and treat everyone involved with respect and dignity. You can't go wrong with that.

Answer (score 5):

None of your concerns are actually your concerns. Your duty is to perform the work they ask you to perform while you're still employed there. Nothing more. This is not an ethical, moral, or legal issue. It may be natural for us to "feel bad", but this is a business relationship. You owe them nothing more than to perform the work for which they pay you.